# Nested ngRepeat with complex JSON-Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I need to show a table. Table consist with a list of objects (I don't know about length of this list), each object have a list of "data".

#### What have:

```js
var list = [
    {
        name: "block1",
        data: [<bigArray1>]
    },
    {
        name: "block2",
        data: [<bigArray2>]
    },
    ....,
    {
        name: "blockN",
        data: [<bigArrayN>]
    }
]
```

**.DATA-Array have always same length in all list.elements!**

Is it possible to show this table?

#### TABLE

```js
|--INDEX-----|--BLOCK1------|---BLOCK2-----|- *** -|----BLOCKN-----|
| 0          | bigarray1[0] | bigarary2[0] |- *** -| bigararyN[0]  | 
| 1          | bigarray1[1] | bigarray2[1] |- *** -| bigarrayN[1]  | 
| 2          | bigarray1[2] | bigarray2[2] |- *** -| bigarrayN[2]  | 
| 3          | bigarray1[3] | bigarray2[3] |- *** -| bigarrayN[3]  | 
|------------|--------------|--------------|-------|---------------|
```

---

**Update 1:**

*data-Array have length between 10.000 - 100.000 or more. And this data I use in mobile App. Solutions with converting and create a new array is from performance , i think, very bad idea... or?*

---

**Update 2:**

**TABLE COLUMN HEADER** length = 1 (for "Nr") + list.length
**TABLE BODY** length = list[].data.length

---

**Update 3:**

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPd76gAJAkWFE05LMoNp?p=preview)**

Comment: Does every bigArray contains the same number of items?

Comment: yes. data-array have same length for all elements in list

Comment: You should look at nested directives...

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th ng-repeat="column in list">{{column.name}}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="index in list[0].data track by $index">
      <td>
        {{$index}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="column in list">
        {{column.data[$parent.$index]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Assuming all "BIGARRAY" are of same length

Comment: I have removed controller code and doing everything inside html.

Comment: don't work. first row with this code => Nr=0, b1[0], b2[1], b3[2], b4[3]

Comment: Ahh!!, my bad. Can you try now? Use $parent.$index instead of $index inside last ng-repeat